# Android to mySQL Database Concurrency using DOM Objects

Tags: android, mysql, xml, dom

I'm pretty comfortable with XML DOM objects and I'm planning to use this from my andriod application do a xmlhttp post to receive a response XML and then read this data to load a list view control. Thinking to store this file in the CacheDir and use it across the application. Not a heavy duty application perse and not in favor of storing anything in the application.

My questions is - If I were to delete/add a lineitem from the listview how do I ensure the database on the server side reflects the same? I'm thinking to create a separate XML and create a new DOM object and pass it over to the server to update the same?

Is there any other better approach? Look forward to hearing from you.

Thanks!